# Android Databinding not updating UI when data changes in the model

Tags: android, data-binding, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-databinding

I have a model CricketModel

```
public class CricketModel extends BaseObservable{
    private String score;
    @Bindable
    public String getScore(){
        return score
    }
    public void setScore(String s){ 
        score=s;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.score); 
   }
}
```

When I call API I get JSONArray, I convert them to CricketModel and add it to a CricketModel list. And pass this list to adapter to display them in the Recycler view.

This is my `item_cricket.xml`

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="cm"
            type="com.panasonic.arbohub.cricket.model.CricketModel" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cv_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp_8"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="3dp">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
               <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_two_s_score"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/tv_one_p_score"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp_16"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_8"
                        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/rl_team_two"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/sp_12"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:text="@{cm.score}"
                        android:visibility="visible" />
            </FrameLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

This is my `ViewHolder`

```
private class CricketViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
         ItemCricketBinding itemCricketBinding;

       public CricketViewHolder(ItemCricketBinding binding) {
          super(binding.getRoot());
          itemCricketBinding = binding;
       }
      public void bind(CricketModel cm){
          itemCricketBinding.setCm(cm);
          itemCricketBinding.executePendingBindings();
      }
    }
```

In my `CricketAdapter.java`

```
 holder.bind(cricketModelList.get(position));
```

API updates once in 1 mi, I'm replacing the cricketModelList with new data that is coming from the API but data is not reflecting in the UI.

Have followed this- https://medium.com/google-developers/android-data-binding-recyclerview-db7c40d9f0e4

**Update:**
After api has been called. I added notifyDataSetChanged() onClickOfthe item view, then new data is reflecting. So model has the new data but its not notifying the UI.

Comment: so `getScore` is never called or it is not called only when you have new results from the network?

Comment: @pskink I debuged, when new data comes getScore is not being called only setScore method gets called

Comment: in what thread `setScore` is called? did you try to call it "manually" from the UI thread (for example from some `OnClickListener`?), also are you 100% sure you are using the same model objects?

Comment: Actually I have declared a variable cm of type CricketModel in xml, which i am setting from the adapter. And i am binding the view with the object in bindViewHolder() method .

I have a  public static List<CricketModel> cricketModelList = new ArrayList<>();  which gets updated by the API, i am passing this object in the adapter

Comment: so what `CricketModel` object are you using in network API callback? is it one that is kept in `cricketModelList`?

Comment: Yes i am using cricketModelList in the API callback

Comment: ok inside `getScore` and `setScore` add `Log.d(TAG, "getScore " + this)` and `Log.d(TAG, "setScore " + this)` and see logcat

Comment: Its getting called and changed data is reflecting earlier it was 311/4 , updated data got printed in setScore() 338/4, but getScore() method is not called.

Comment: i have no idea what you are talking about, what `311/4 `? what do you see on the logcat when you add those two `Log.d` calls?

Comment: 311/4 was earlier stored in score variable, which later got updated to 338/4 when api is called.

Comment: what do you see on the logcat when you add those two `Log.d` calls?

Comment: for Log.d(TAG,"getScore"+this) -
06-22 18:03:07.161 12836-12836/com.test. D/CricketModel: getValue com.test.cricket.model.CricketModel@1beae3c
06-22 18:03:07.272 12836-12836/com.test. D/CricketModel: setValue com.test.cricket.model.CricketModel@734722d
06-22 18:03:07.277 12836-12836/com.test. D/CricketModel: setValue com.test.cricket.model.CricketModel@7ec8362
06-22 18:03:07.280 12836-12836/com.test. D/CricketModel: setValue com.test.cricket.model.CricketModel@f87fcf3

Comment: so why the model object is always different when calling setScore: 734722d 7ec8362 and f87fcf3?

Comment: for Log.d(TAG,"getScore"+this.score) -
06-22 17:57:32.033 12836-12836/com.test.cricket D/CricketModel: setValue 311/4
06-22 17:57:32.045 12836-12836/com.test.cricket D/CricketModel: setValue 142/10
06-22 17:57:32.050 12836-12836/com.test.cricket D/CricketModel: setValue 142/10

Comment: There are 3 models in the list, coming from the API, i am displaying them in RecyclerView

Comment: your `CricketModel` is always different when calling `setScore`

Comment: When new data comes from the API i am creating new model and adding to the list, as there is a chance of additional model coming from the API. Should i check if model is already present, if yes then update else add it to list?

Comment: try this: https://pastebin.com/a0R8VbXM and check if it works or not

Comment: @pskink Thank you so much for your time, it worked. I was replacing the model earlier with new model, which is why it was not working. Now I changed the values inside the model then it worked.

Comment: so now i hope you know what you did wrong

Comment: @pskink Yes, can you please put the pastebin link and small write up on my mistake. I would like to select it as the right answer.

Comment: What was the issue?

Answer (score 0):

you should set "itemCricketBinding.lifecycleOwner" in bind method, not the best practice and I'm not sure about the performance but if you wonder why that not work, That was the reason.